# Static Var closure returns Type.Type instead of Type

Tags: swift

I try to break, count and later join objects inside another class.
So I build protocol:

```
typealias DataBreaker<T> = () -> [Double]
typealias DataJoiner<T> = (_ particles: [Double]) -> T

protocol SpaceIntepolatable {
    associatedtype Atom
    var breaker:DataBreaker<Atom> {get}
    static var joiner:DataJoiner<Atom> {get}
}
```

and build an extension for Point:

```
extension Point:SpaceIntepolatable {

    typealias Atom = Point
    var breaker:DataBreaker<Atom> {
        return {
            return [self.x, self.y]
        }
}
    static var joiner:DataJoiner<Atom> {
        return {particles in
            return Atom(x: particles[0], y: particles[1])
        }
    }
}
```

Till now is fine. I can break `Point` into an `Array<Double>`

```
let particles = atom.breaker()
```

but joining

```
let newAtom = Atom.joiner(particles)
```

causes a compiler error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Atom.Atom' to specified type 'Atom'
```

It's probably because `joiner` is a static. But how to avoid it and get `Atom` as a result?

Comment: You will have to show the context for the joining.

Comment: It's simple. Inside a class Space<Atom:SpaceIntepolatable>  in some function:let particlesA = atomA.breaker()
            let particlesB = atomB.breaker()
            
            let particles:[Double] = interpolateArrays(bounds: bounds, at: at, array: (set1: particlesA, set2: particlesB))
            
            let newAtom: Atom = Atom.joiner(particles)

Comment: That would work for me if I lose that `: Atom` on the last line. Or replace it with the correct `Atom.Atom`, since we are talking about the `Point.Atom` type here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call it on `Point` when you are outside the scope of the class.

```
let newAtom = Point.joiner(particles)
```

**Edit:**

You say that you have a generic class that looks like this:

```
class Space<Atom: SpaceIntepolatable> {
    func test() {
        let particles: [Double] = [0, 1]
        let newAtom: Atom = Atom.joiner(particles)
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that the type of `newAtom` is incorrect. The `SpaceIntepolatable` protocol doesn't specify that `Point` and `Point.Atom` are the same type. Therefore `Atom` (`Point`) and `Atom.Atom` (`Point.Atom`) are not considered the same. What we want is `Atom.Atom`. Or we can just let the type to be inferred:

```
let newAtom: Atom.Atom = Atom.joiner(particles)

let newAtom = Atom.joiner(particles)
```

In general it is advisable not to reuse type names because then you get things like `Atom.Atom`. Maybe you actually want something like this:

```
protocol SpaceIntepolatable {
    var breaker: DataBreaker<Self> { get }
    static var joiner: DataJoiner<Self> { get }
}
```

and lose the `Atom` typealias completely, then:

```
class Space<Atom: SpaceIntepolatable> {
    func test() {
        let particles: [Double] = [0, 1]
        let newAtom: Atom = Atom.joiner(particles)
    }
}
```

will actually work.

Comment: But inside a class I don't know Atom is Double, Point or Whatever. Class is declared as Space<Atom:SpaceIntepolatable>.

Comment: When I changed to Point.joiner I got "Cannot convert value of type 'Point.Atom' (aka 'Point') to specified type 'Atom'"